# Quando e como começou o Pretérito Perfeito Composto do Indicativo a implicar repetição?

Tags: mudanças-históricas, tempo-verbal

Em português, o Pretérito Perfeito Composto do Indicativo tem um uso bastante diferente da maioria das outras línguas próximas; possui aquilo a que por vezes se chama um **aspeto iterativo**. A única exceção moderna que conheço são frases como "tenho dito" e "tenho concluído". Isto é verdade quer em Portugal, quer no Brasil, o que sugere que é um fenómeno antigo. Exemplos tirados do CETEMPúblico:

> Os últimos anos não *têm sido* fáceis para Artur Jorge.
>   Dos lançamentos que a Lusomundo *tem feito* do seu catálogo Goldwin, este «Jardim Profano» é seguramente um dos mais insólitos.

O significado é diferente de *foram fáceis* e de *fez*; em ambos os casos há uma ideia de repetição, ou no mínimo de continuidade/durativa na primeira frase.

Este não é de todo o caso da forma correspondente do conjuntivo:

> A: Espero que tenhas compreendido.
>   B: Compreendi, sim.

Adicionamente, o PPC é a forma onde é menos provável que "haver" seja usado como auxiliar. A frase:

> [Q]uem não achar verdade e exactidão no que hei dito e hei de dizer, tem à mão o remédio, mostre-me a verdade[...]

É engraçada, mas dificilmente seria dita hoje em dia e a frase:

> Ele há estudado muito.

Soa mais a espanhol do que a português e (talvez por isso) não vejo qualquer aspeto iterativo.

Perguntas:

1. Quando é se deu a transformação?
2. O que levou o português a seguir este caminho, quando no espanhol, pelo contrário, o fenómeno é até a forma composta tomar o lugar da simples na maioria das situações (em regiões como Madrid)?
3. A muito forte preferência por ter estará relacionada? Em exemplos históricos, está o uso de "haver" também associado a uma ideia iterativa?

Comment: Não consigo perceber pela pergunta o que é o aspeto iterativo. Podes pôr um exemplo explícito? Para os novatos. :)

Comment: @ANeves Acrescentei dois exemplos.

Comment: Fernão M. Pinto já no século XVI escrevia _a outras algumas tem acontecido_ com o sentido moderno. Única ocorrência em três páginas. Mas nenhuma das muitas ocorrências do pretérito simples dá ideia de iteração.

Comment: @Jacinto Experimenta procurar `[ter].[vp*] [vk*]` em http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/, século XVIII. Verás que há ocurrências do composto sem ideia de iterativa ou durativa. Exemplo: "... que entenda à vista do que me dizeis, porém juro-vos que ainda nao tenho visto coisas que me pareçam melhor ou mais dignas de ser amadas."

Comment: Estou a encontrar as duas interpretações, e casos ambíguos. Os dois sentidos devem ter sido usados em paralelo

Comment: Relacionado: [How did English and Portuguese develop the construction “have+pp”?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/987/how-did-english-and-portuguese-develop-the-construction-havepp)

Comment: Ouvi recentemente um comentador de futebol (alguns usam rotineiramente o indicativo em vez do subjuntivo em orações subordinadas condicionais) dizer algo como, "se a bola tem entrado, teria sido um golo espetacular" -- isto é ainda o uso perfectivo antigo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando se deu a transformação?

Procurando superficialmente uma publicação achei:

---

**Mendes, Ronald Beline. "A evolução do passado composto em português."Todas as Letras-Revista de Língua e Literatura 7.2 (2009).**

“A principal questão que motivou nossa análise foi: como a perífrase TP deixou de ser usada para expressar aspecto perfectivo (resultado), passando a expressar apenas imperfectivo (duração e iteração)?”

“o uso imperfectivo de TP torna-se prototípico no **século XIX**, em detrimento de seu uso perfectivo – algo bastante distinto do que se observa no início do século XVIII e na passagem de um século ao outro.”

“Juntamente com a pergunta sobre “como” se deu a mudança, poderíamos perguntar “por que” ela ocorreu… O exame qualitativo dos empregos de TP em séculos passados nos mostra que a diferença entre o resultativo (resultado presente de uma ação ou evento passado) e o imperfectivo (alongamento do passado para o presente) pode residir na focalização de um ou outro ponto de um esquema temporal – aspectual – visualizado pelo usuário da língua.”

---

Acho que é melhor atender as outras perguntas por separado, p.e. existe diferença entre o pretérito composto em espanhol e português?. Mas :P…

---

Em:

**Pereira, Aline Amarante. "O uso do pretérito perfecto compuesto e indefinido por estudantes brasileiros El uso del pretérito perfecto compuesto e indefinido por hablantes brasileños."**

“O pretérito composto expressa uma ação repetida e uma continuação de uma ação até o momento presente. Já o pretérito compuesto expressa uma ação passada que mantém uma relação com o momento presente da enunciação, seja em ação, seja em sentido. Acredita-se que seja esse um dos pontos da dificuldade do brasileiro em compreender o pretérito compuesto, pois, embora seja similar ao pretérito composto do português, difere-se com relação ao uso e em português quase não se utiliza esse tempo verbal e outra dificuldade é pelo fato de o pretérito composto do português, em geral, ser substituído pelo tempo simples."

"O pretérito compuesto é mais utilizado no espanhol peninsular (Espanha), do que no espanhol da América. Alguns autores destacam que a variante americana não vê diferenças entre os pretéritos indefinido e compuesto, o que os leva ao uso de ambos da mesma maneira”

---

É importante notar que não existe um espanhol de América só, eu tenho falado com peruanos que utilizam indistintamente o simples e o composto, em quanto eu, centroamericano, os utilizo de jeito distinto, além o jeito em que os espanhóis usam o composto também é diferente ao mesoamericano. O que posso confirmar é que existem pelo menos três variações do composto em espanhol.

Comment: Parabéns. Isto é que foi uma entrada de leão na comunidade: esta pergunta estava sem resposta há meses.

Comment: Também pode ser interessante notar que no asturiano (e que saiba eu também no mirandês) a construção *tener (ter) + part. passado* só tem o significado iterativo/imperfectivo, não só no presente como em português. Não sei quando dito uso começou, e a minha cópia da história da língua perdeu-a Correios =\ pergunto-me se também existe no galego.

Answer (score -3):

A frase *ele há estudado muito* está errada.

**Ele** - Indica que a frase refere uma 3ª pessoa do singular

**muito** - É simplesmente um nome comum

A questão parece estar em **há estudado** . Enquanto que no castelhano isto seria correcto, em português simplesmente não é correcto.

**Há** - denota um acontecimento presente.

**Estudado** - denota um acontecimento passado

---

Sim, existe a excepção onde *Há bocado* , *Há três anos*.

No entanto *Há* não é em sim um passado, mas sim um presente, no sentido em que existe uma distancia temporal. ***Há*** três anos, ***Há*** x tempo, ***Há*** distância temporal

Desta forma, concluí-se que *Ele há estudado muito* é uma frase errada, e que, em bom português seria "Ele estudou muito" ou "Ele havia estudado muito". Devido a isto, presumo que não seja necessário responder às questões, visto que elas baseiam-se numa premissa errada, demonstrada por esta resposta.

Comment: Isto não responde de todo à pergunta, além de metade estar errado ou posto em termos muito imprecisos.