# Pequei, Senhor; mas não porque hei pecado

Tags: significado, verbos

Qual a função do verbo haver, em “Pequei, Senhor; mas não porque hei pecado”, de Gregório de Matos?

O [Priberam traz as seguintes definições para *haver*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/haver), como verbo transitivo:

> 1. Ter, possuir, estar na posse de.
> 2. Conseguir.
> 3. Considerar, julgar.
> 4. Existir (ex.: há café acabado de fazer; há pessoas assim). [Verbo impessoal]
> 5. Acontecer, suceder (ex.: hoje à noite há festa; houve dois acidentes graves). [Verbo impessoal]
> 6. Ser decorrido ou ter passado determinado período de tempo (ex.: são amigos há mais de trinta anos; vi-o há uma hora na biblioteca). [Verbo impessoal

Nenhuma delas parece se adequar perfeitamente ao trecho em questão.

Comment: Não entendo o ditado, então não posso responder com certeza, mas por que transitivo e não auxiliar, já que *pecado* pode ser particípio?

Comment: Você tem razão. Eu estava partindo do pressuposto que "pecado", neste caso, é substantivo. De qualquer modo, se for este o caso, o significado do verso continua obscuro. Basicamente: "pequei, mas não porque pequei". Do outro lado, tratando-se de um poema barroco, talvez isso tenha sido intencional...

Comment: É preciso o verso seguinte para compreender: *Pequei Senhor: mas não porque hei pecado/ Da vossa Alta Piedade me despido* (*despido* = *despeço*). A minha interpretação é: não é por ter pecado que me despeço da vossa Alta Piedade.

Comment: Obrigado, Jacinto. Você pode transformar esse seu comentário em uma resposta, para que eu possa aceitá-la?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O verbo *haver* é usado nesse verso como verbo auxiliar, tal como acontece uns versos mais abaixo no [soneto completo](http://www.infoescola.com/escritores/gregorio-de-matos-guerra/) (ênfase minha):

> Pequei Senhor: mas não porque **hei pecado**,
>   Da vossa Alta Piedade me despido: [= *me despeço*]
>   Antes, quanto mais tenho delinqüido,
>   Vos tenho a perdoar mais empenhado.
>
> Se basta a vos irar tanto pecado,
>   A abrandar-vos sobeja um só gemido:
>   Que a mesma culpa, que vos **há ofendido**,
>   Vos tem para o perdão lisonjeado.
>
> Se uma ovelha perdida, já cobrada,
>   Glória tal, e prazer tão repentino
>   Vos deu, como afirmais na Sacra História,
>
> Eu sou, Senhor, ovelha desgarrada;
>   Cobrai-a; e não queirais, Pastor Divino,
>   Perder na vossa ovelha a vossa glória

A minha interpretação dos dois primeiros versos é:

> Pequei Senhor: *mas não é por ter pecado que me despeço da vossa Alta Piedade* = *mas apesar de ter pecado não me despeço da vossa Alta Piedade*.

Atualmente o pretérito perfeito composto *haver + particípio passado* é relativamente pouco usado, ao contrário de *ter + particípio passado*. Mas era frequente no século XVII, ao tempo do autor [Gregório de Matos (1636-96)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greg%C3%B3rio_de_Matos). No entanto, enquanto atualmente *tenho pecado* signfica que pequei contínua ou repetidamente até ao presente, naquela altura significava apenas que cometi pecados no passado: só mais tarde é que *ter + particípio passado* passou a implicar necessariamente a ideia de continuidade ou repetição da ação até ao presente. Quando é que esta mudança no sentido do pretérito perfeito composto se deu é objeto [desta pergunta.](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/quando-e-como-come%C3%A7ou-o-pret%C3%A9rito-perfeito-composto-do-indicativo-a-implicar-rep)