# Há uma palavra que significa "virar bom"? Como "*desaginar"?

Tags: etimologia, verbos, palavra-para-ideia

Há uma palavra do criolu cabo-verdiano de São Vicente, com morfologia como se fosse uma palavra portuguesa *"*desaginar"* com significado "virar bom, hábil, apto [em tal coisa]". Então uma pessoa pode ser também *"*desaginado"* numa coisa, que agora ele pode faze-lo bem. (/dzajiná/, /dzajinót/)

Andei a procurar esta palavra em dicionários portugueses, com diferentes variações ("*aginar", "*desengenhar", `grep -E /usr/share/dict/portuguese`, etc.) mas nunca consegui encontrar uma palavra parecida.

**Existe um verbo com significado "virar bom/apto/hábil"?**
Será que tem ligação a esta palavra crioula?

Exemplos de frase que podiam utilizar esta palavra:

- > Antes, ele não sabia cozinhar. Mas agora ele é ____*do*.
- > Muito bom, olha quem já _______!
- > Eu tinha ____*do* nesta área muito antes do que pensas.

Acho que "melhorar" não é igual porque eu posso melhorar um bocadinho sem virar perito.

Comment: Idealmente pões umas frases exemplo, em que deixas o "*desaginar". E uma parte esperada das respostas passa a ser também construir essa frase de maneira que faça sentido. :)

Comment: Nunca ouvi o desaginar

Comment: "Mas agora ele **há** _____"; os cabo-verdianos dizem **ele há desaginado**? No português seria preciso recuar uns séculos para ouvir *ele há desasnado*; agora diríamos *ele desasnou*.

Comment: @Jacinto desculpe, confundi *haver* com *ter*. E talvez pensei em "tinha __do", vou editar.

Comment: Me desculpa mas não entendo como uma frase como Eu tinha etc. ou Antes ele não sabia seja cabo verdeano. Parece português de Portugal. Parece que a estrutura das frases não é realmente crioulo,

Comment: @Lambie a minha pergunta é sobre a língua portuguesa, apesar de ser motivada pelo crioulo. Eu estava a buscar palavras portuguesas. Por isso dei exemplos de frases em português, com semelhança aos usos que ouvi no crioulo.

Comment: Tudo bem. Então a palavra é crioula mas não as frases. O crioulo quase não usa pronomes.

Comment: @Lambie não usa pronomes? Como assim? Acho que são muito usados, seja na Praia ou em São Vicente.

Comment: @DanGetz, não é preciso pedir desculpa. Já se disse coisas como ["hei pecado" ( = "pequei") e "há ofendido" (= "ofendeu")](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3384/pequei-senhor-mas-n%c3%a3o-porque-hei-pecado). A minha dúvida era se o crioulo teria preservado construções dessas.

Comment: Aonde eu moro já ouvi muita gente falando crioulo, e eles nunca usam: ele, ela, tu etc. ‘Ele perdeu o livro dele na escola’ = E perde si libru na skola. http://www.iltec.pt/divling/_pdfs/linguas_crioulo_cv.pdf//bo e = ‘tu és’ //ele ou ela tem = e ten

Comment: @Lambie o "E" na sua frase inicial, também com realização "el", é pronome. Significa "ele" ou "ela". E "bo" (ou "bu") significa "tu", então também é pronome. Veja 2.3.2.4 no seu PDF para mais exemplos.

Comment: @Jacinto no crioulo, as formas como "hei tomado" e "tomei", junto com o imperativo (e talvez subjuntivo) tem a mesma forma. Dependente no dialecto e a palavra, parece o com o presente indicativo da terceira pessoa (apesar de indicar geralmente o passado), o imperativo de "tu", ou o infinitivo sem o "r". (tôma / t'má)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A única coisa que me vem à cabeça, com pronúncia e sentido parecidos, é ***desasnar***, pronunciado como *desajnar*  (*desa*[ʒ]*nar*) por quem chia o s (como portugueses e cariocas) e *desa*[z]*nar* por quem não chia. O *desaginar* de Cabo Verde corresponde mais ou menos à aceção 2 do [dicionário Micahelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/desasnar/):

> **desasnar**
>
> vtd
>   **1** Ensinar noções básicas a; alfabetizar, instruir: “Ele está ainda muito pequeno, mas vou tratar de o ir **desasnando** aqui mesmo em casa, e quando tiver doze ou catorze anos há de me entrar para a escola” (Manuel Antônio de Almeida)
>
> vint e vpr
>   **2** Adquirir noções básicas sobre determinado assunto; aprender: *O filho **desasnou** com a ajuda do computador. O menino **desasnou-se** com muita leitura.*
>
> vtd
>   **3** Corrigir engano ou erro de. *Ela está convencida de que tem razão, e não há meios de **desasná-la***.

A palavra vem de *asno*. Eu nem a conhecia. O que eu sempre ouvi em Portugal, nas aceções 1 e 2 acima, é [*desemburrar* (Michaelis)](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/desemburrar/). Mas já vem em 1713 no [dicionário de Raphael Bluteau](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ngoKPY6hwUoC&pg=PA94&dq=%22Desasnar%20dizfe%20vulgarmente%20de%20quem%20enfina%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx49P3mbjpAhWqxoUKHXexC6kQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22Desasnar%20dizfe%20vulgarmente%20de%20quem%20enfina%22&f=false).

Procurando na literatura, muitos exemplo de *desasnar* são acerca de aprender a ler e fazer contas. Mas encontram-se também muitos como os teu exemplos de *desaginar*. Temos por exemplo um moço que estava [desasnando bem no harmônico](https://books.google.pt/books?id=KAFCCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT32&lpg=PT32&dq=%22desasnando%20bem%20no%20harm%C3%B4nico%22&source=bl&ots=gWr5NAa6UL&sig=ACfU3U1UgYJgFrcrbT_oHK1SfDz9rSNbzQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQhomIn7vpAhVuA2MBHRgRCqkQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22desasnando%20bem%20no%20harm%C3%B4nico%22&f=false) (já tocava com desembaraço); ir [desasnando na dança](https://books.google.pt/books?id=KAFCCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT23&dq=%22%C3%89%20pra%20ir%20desasnando,%20mui%C3%A9.%20Daqui%20a%20pouco%20t%C3%A3o%20umas%20cachorra%20da%20molesta%20pra%20dan%C3%A7a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7o-mHorvpAhUQlhQKHV0PA8sQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%89%20pra%20ir%20desasnando%2C%20mui%C3%A9.%20Daqui%20a%20pouco%20t%C3%A3o%20umas%20cachorra%20da%20molesta%20pra%20dan%C3%A7a%22&f=false), na [dalitografia](https://books.google.pt/books?id=71N9AAAAMAAJ&q=%22Estou%20desasnando%20agora%22&dq=%22Estou%20desasnando%20agora%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9ppmGo7vpAhVLUhoKHblaC4wQ6AEIKjAA), no [ofício de pedreiro](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ee4YAAAAYAAJ&q=desasnando&dq=desasnando&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVwvP60rrpAhXBA2MBHYXfB9EQ6AEIeTAI), no [ofício de escrevente de um tabelião](https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/O_Garatuja/XII); alguém que já estava [desasnado no atendimento ao público numa bodega](https://books.google.pt/books?id=sQwsAAAAYAAJ&q=%22trabalhava%20na%20bodega%20de%20um%20cunhado,%20atendendo%20ao%20p%C3%BAblico.%20Desasnado%20nesta%20atividade%22&dq=%22trabalhava%20na%20bodega%20de%20um%20cunhado,%20atendendo%20ao%20p%C3%BAblico.%20Desasnado%20nesta%20atividade%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiA0LCFpbvpAhUux4UKHceHDKQQ6AEIKDAA).

Também temos *desasnar* no sentido de aprender sobre a vida, se desenvolver pessoalmente. Por exemplo, um deputado principiante que se foi [desasnando aos poucos](https://books.google.pt/books?id=mXUNAAAAYAAJ&q=desasnando&dq=desasnando&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVwvP60rrpAhXBA2MBHYXfB9EQ6AEI4AEwEw) no convívio com os colegas, os índios que [foram desasnando](https://books.google.pt/books?id=VvArAAAAYAAJ&q=desasnando&dq=desasnando&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVwvP60rrpAhXBA2MBHYXfB9EQ6AEIwgEwEA) um tipo, fazendo-o ver que eles também eram gente; e temos até um homem que [foi desasnado no trato com mulheres](https://books.google.pt/books?id=z2BgDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT149&dq=%22neg%C3%B3cio%20com%20Luisinha%20o%20tivesse%20desasnado%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf5tDLqLvpAhUHlhQKHR5XBScQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=%22neg%C3%B3cio%20com%20Luisinha%20o%20tivesse%20desasnado%22&f=false).

Estes exemplos vêm todos do Brasil. Eu em Portugal não conhecia *desasnar* (só *desemburrar*); é possível que no Brasil seja mais comum.

Comment: Muito obrigado, tem que ser isto!

Comment: Pois é, um asno é um burro, ou uma jumenta. O adjetivo é parvo ou ignorante. Então desasnar é tirar a ingnorância do pobre fulano. Mas aqui é mais uma questão de formação.....o fato de se tornar apto, etc. nem sempre vem dos estudos....

Comment: @DanGetz, sempre às ordens. Também creio que o *desaginar* veio mesmo do *desasnar*. Até alguém ter ideia melhor...

Comment: *Desasnar* também significa aprender a fazer algo, adquirir competências. Encontram-se exemplos de estar "desasnando bem no harmônico", na dança, na cozinha, no ofício de escrevente de tabelião, na colher de pedreiro, no viver em sociedade, e até nas coisas do amor! Os exemplos que encontrei vêm todos do Brasil. Possivelmente *desasnar* manteve-se mais em uso lá.

Comment: @DanGetz,editei a resposta com uma porção de exemplos de uso de *desasnar*. Uma curiosidade: *desasnar* fica mais parecido com *deaginar* quando o s é chiado, como em Portugal e no Rio; no crioulo, o s é chiado? [Nesta canção](https://www.google.com/search?q=preparado+rapaz+100+juiz&oq=prepa&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j46j69i57j0l2j69i61j69i60l2.1563j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), o s parece-me chiado numas palavras (*e**s**quiva, e**s**posa*, mais ao princípio) e não chiado noutras (*de**s**culpa, ve**s**tido*, mais para o fim).

Comment: @Jacinto depende no dialecto, mas nessa canção eles estão a falar o dialecto da Praia, em que o s não é chiado. (Pelo menos ao nível do meu ouvido.) Em São Vicente, é chiado, por isso que pensei que ouvi *"desagenar"*. Não sei se *desasnar* é usado na Praia.

Answer (score 1):

O mais próximo que consigo pensar seria o uso de verbos como "aperfeiçoar-se" ou "especializar-se". Segundo o [dicionário Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=aperfei%C3%A7oar):

> **aperfeiçoar**
>
> vpr Adquirir maior grau de instrução ou aptidão: *Aperfeiçoou-se,
>   estudando incansavelmente.*

> **especializar**
>
> vpr
>   Dedicar-se a uma determinada área ou especialidade de estudo, pesquisa e/ou tratamento; tornar-se especialista em: *Especializou-se em dermatologia.*

Quanto às frases-exemplo dadas, seriam então:

> Muito bom, olha quem já se especializou!
>
> Muito bom, olha quem já se aperfeiçoou! *(soa um pouco estranho, admito)*

> Antes, ele não sabia cozinhar. Mas agora já se especializou nisso.
>
> Antes, ele não sabia cozinhar. Mas agora já se aperfeiçoou.